# php docBlock - Put type into @param, if it leads to exception?

Tags: php, coding-style

Given you got the following method:

```
/**
* @throws \Exception
**/
function foo($param): void
{
    if (!(is_string($param) | is_array($param))) {
        throw new \Exception('Param is neither string nor array!');
    }

    postProcess($param);
}
```

The method itself accepts all parameter types, but throws, if the parameter is neither a string nor an array.
Which of the following `@param`-Tags would you prefer for this method?

1. `@param mixed`
2. `@param string|array`

Comment: Usually **mixed** will use.

Answer (score 1):

I presume it is **opinion based**, but I would set `@param string|array` so as to give a **more clear explanation**, which types are supported. Also you can add a comment (to `@throws` or to `@params` or both) like:

```
/**
 * @throws \Exception If the provided argument is not array or string
 *
 * @param string|array $param Bla-bla-bla. If not array or string - \Exception will be thrown.
 */
```